# Find the maximum or minimum value of the function $f(x) = − \frac{x^2}{3} + 2x + 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the minimum or maximum value for this function? Do I multiply the function by $3$ to get rid of the 34 in the denominator?

Comment: Why bother? Just differentiate!

Comment: Multiplying by a positive constant does not change the $x$ at which the maximum is reached. So if it makes things simpler for you, go ahead. You can achieve essentially the same thing by bringing the expression to the common denominator $3$. In this case, if you are differentiating, there is no reason to bother, but if you are doing it by completing the square, it will help.

Comment: There is no minimum, the parabola points down. Complete the square.

Comment: Can you show me?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Tags: [tag:algebra-precalculus]

Answer (score 5):

Well if you dont have calculus then you complete the square, and, like you say, multiply by $3$ to make our life easier, it wont change the location of the max or min. 
so we have 
$$-x^2+6x+12=21-(x-3)^2$$
so there is no minimum but a maximum occurs at $x=3$, and its value is $7$, we must remember to divide by $3$ again.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the function by $3$ will multiply the function value of the maximum or minimum by $3$, but leave the $x$-value unchanged.

This is a quadratic function, i.e., the largest exponent on any $x$ term is $2$.  This means that the sign of the coefficient on this term determines whether we are dealing with a maximum or a minimum.  Since the sign is negative, the parabola "opens downwards" and there must be a maximum.

Then the only necessity is to determine where the maximum is.  Using the quadratic formula, the zeroes of this function must be at

$$x=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4-4(-\frac 13)(4)}}{-\frac 23}$$

$$=3\pm3\sqrt{\frac 73}$$

The maximum must be at the center value of $x$ where the values are equal on either side, which must then be $x=3$ with a function value of $f(3)=7$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple formula for determining the extremum (minimum if $a>0$, maximum if $a<0$):

$$x=-\frac{b}{2a}$$

By plugging the $x$-value back into the equation, you can find the corresponding $y$-value.

I'll show a simple proof (using differentiation):

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

$$f'(x)=2ax+b$$

$$2ax+b=0$$

$$x=-\frac{b}{2a}$$

In this case: we have $a=-\frac{1}{3}, b=2$, so $x=-\frac{2}{2\cdot-\frac{1}{3}}=3$. $f(3)=-\frac{1}{3}(3)^2+2(3)+4=7$.

Hence, the maximum (in this case) is at (3, 7).

[image]